# Cordova and JDK contradict each other: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-8, sdk

I recently started using Cordova to create cross-platform apps, and want to run the sample Cordova app in an Android emulator on my computer. The emulation command seems to only work if I have environment variables pointing to JDK 1.8 ONLY. When the command line tries to launch the emulator, I get issues that can be remedied by adding newer JDK to environment variables, except doing that means I can't start the emulation process! How can I fix this?

[My image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiEjG.jpg)

I've been seeing this WAY too much.

Comment: only JDK 1.8 is supported. What is the problem you get when using JDK 1.8?

Comment: When I use JDK 1.8, Android Studio doesn't boot. To use JDK 1.8, I have to disable the new JDK though.

Comment: that's strange, I use JDK 1.8 and Android Studio loads fine. Anyway, Android Studio not loading is not a Cordova problem. Can you run/install the cordova app from command line?

Comment: When I try to run emulation: https://imgur.com/a/OdVLZXX
My java installation: https://imgur.com/a/7L6aXlQ Environment Variables: https://imgur.com/a/IRcpDzJ User variable PATH: https://imgur.com/a/0QpGizT System variable PATH: https://imgur.com/a/vfiYcIO

Comment: your JAVA_HOME points to both 1.8 and 10, remove the 10 path.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rjNmDeN Is my JAVA_HOME variable set wrong?

Comment: try removing the ; at the end

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the comments into an answer.

Cordova requires `JDK` 1.8 to work, the message about "or greater" is wrong and has been updated, won't appear on next release.

And your `JAVA_HOME` has to point to the JDK directory, just to the 1.8 one and not end in `;`